# Как вытянуть данные с 3й таблицы в yii2?

Tags: php, sql, yii2

Есть такой запрос

```
$bloggers_neutral_db = BloggerForm::find()
    ->leftJoin('node_klient_blogger', '`node_klient_blogger`.`id_blogger` = `bloggers`.`id`')
    ->where(['node_klient_blogger.id_klient' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id, 'node_klient_blogger.long_list' => 0])
    ->orderBy('id desc')
    ->all();
```

Мне нужно подключить 3ю таблицу `data_platforms` и вытянуть данные так же как и тут

```
->where(['node_klient_blogger.id_klient' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id, 'node_klient_blogger.long_list' => 0])
```

То есть, вытянуть данные из таблицы `BloggerForm` , где в таблице `node_klient_blogger` будут совпадать значения и в таблице `data_platforms` тоже будут совпадать значения

**Пробую сделать так**

```
$bloggers_neutral_db = BloggerForm::find()
            ->leftJoin('node_klient_blogger', '`node_klient_blogger`.`id_blogger` = `bloggers`.`id`')
            ->leftJoin('data_platforms', '`data_platforms`.`id_blogger` = `bloggers`.`id`')
            ->where(['node_klient_blogger.id_klient' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id, 'node_klient_blogger.long_list' => 0])
            ->where(['data_platforms.id_platform' => Yii::$app->request->get('platrorm')])
            ->orderBy('id desc')
            ->all();
```

Но выводит только через 2й where игнорируя первый

**И так попытался сделать, выводит но только из 1 таблицы**

```
$bloggers_neutral_db = BloggerForm::find()
            ->leftJoin('node_klient_blogger', '`node_klient_blogger`.`id_blogger` = `bloggers`.`id`')
            ->leftJoin('data_platforms', '`data_platforms`.`id_blogger` = `node_klient_blogger`.`id_blogger`')
            ->where([
                'node_klient_blogger.id_klient' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id, 'node_klient_blogger.long_list' => 0 ,
                'data_platforms.id_platform' => Yii::$app->request->get('platrorm')
            ])
            ->orderBy('id desc')
            ->all();
```

**С andWhere**

```
$bloggers_neutral_db = BloggerForm::find()
            ->leftJoin('node_klient_blogger', '`node_klient_blogger`.`id_blogger` = `bloggers`.`id`')
            ->leftJoin('data_platforms', '`data_platforms`.`id_blogger` = `node_klient_blogger`.`id_blogger`')
            ->Where(['node_klient_blogger.id_klient' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id, 'node_klient_blogger.long_list' => 0])
            ->andWhere(['data_platforms.id_platform' => Yii::$app->request->get('platrorm')])
            ->orderBy('id desc')
            ->all();
```

Comment: Что значит вытянуть? Из data_platforms  вытянуть?  ещё один left join нужен как минимум

Comment: Написал такой запрос

$bloggers_neutral_db = BloggerForm::find()
            ->leftJoin('node_klient_blogger', '``node_klient_blogger``.`id_blogger` = `bloggers`.`id`')
            ->leftJoin('data_platforms', '`data_platforms`.`id_blogger` = `bloggers`.`id`')
            ->where(['node_klient_blogger.id_klient' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id, 'node_klient_blogger.long_list' => 0])
            ->where(['data_platforms.id_platform' => Yii::$app->request->get('platrorm')])
            ->orderBy('id desc')
            ->all();

Но выводит данные по последнему where игнорируя первого

Comment: where  .. и . [andWhere](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#andWhere()-detail)

Comment: По таблице `node_klient_blogger` выбирает, игнорируя вторую

$bloggers_neutral_db = BloggerForm::find()
            ->leftJoin('node_klient_blogger', '`node_klient_blogger`.`id_blogger` = `bloggers`.`id`')
            ->leftJoin('data_platforms', '`data_platforms`.`id_blogger` = `node_klient_blogger`.`id_blogger`')
            ->Where(['node_klient_blogger.id_klient' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id, 'node_klient_blogger.long_list' => 0])
            ->andWhere(['data_platforms.id_platform' => Yii::$app->request->get('platrorm')])
            ->orderBy('id desc')
            ->all();

Comment: Тут я имею введу, что мне нужно вытащить из таблицы `BloggerForm` все записи , где в одной таблице id = столько то , а в другой таблице id столько то

Comment: И получается , что 2 таблицы `data_platforms` и `node_klient_blogger` отсеивают не нужные записи в таблице `BloggerForm`

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо! с andWhere заработало. Я криво в get запрос написал, сейчас всё ок

Answer (score 0):

```
$bloggers_neutral_db = BloggerForm::find()
            ->leftJoin('node_klient_blogger', '`node_klient_blogger`.`id_blogger` = `bloggers`.`id`')
            ->leftJoin('data_platforms', '`data_platforms`.`id_blogger` = `node_klient_blogger`.`id_blogger`')
            ->Where(['node_klient_blogger.id_klient' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id, 'node_klient_blogger.long_list' => 0])
            ->andWhere(['data_platforms.id_platform' => Yii::$app->request->get('platform')])
            ->orderBy('id desc')
            ->all();
```